# Can I make a File final if I want to write to it later?

Tags: java, file, io, final

Is it okay to make an object of type File, which I later would like to write into, have a final declaration? I'd like to pass it to a `Runnable` inner class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`final` declaration allows you to write/read into, but not change the reference of the object.

```
final File fileRef = new File("/path/to/my/file.txt");
fileRef = new File("/new/path/to/file"); // illegal
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem, `final` doesn't mean that the object itself can't alter its state. It just means that the variable can't be reassigned. So it applies to a different thing.

In addition to this, a `File` is just an abstract representation of a file system file or folder. You don't write through a `File` object, you use it to open a stream (eg. `FileWriter`).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Making a variable `final` means you can't change it to point to a different object. You can totally do whatever you want with the object it does point to, though.

```
final File file = new File("foo");

Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        file.renameTo("bar");    // Cool.
        file.delete();           // Cool.
        file = new File("bar");  // Whoa. Not cool.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

An object from `File` class is an abstract representation of a file or directory from the real hard drive. It is not the physical file or folder.

If you mark the variable as `final` then it cannot be re assigned. That's all. Marking the variable as `final` won't make the physical file immutable. If the `Runnable` is created as an anonymous class and the `File` variable is local to the method (parameter or local variable), then yes. Otherwise, no.